# Reraising an exception so it's handled in the same block

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have code that's a bit like this:

```
try:
    # do stuff
except SomeSpecificException as sse:
    if sse.some_property == some_special_value:
        # handle the exception in a special way
    else:
        handle_exception_normally()
except:
    handle_exception_normally()
```

I want to catch the specific exception and handle it in a special way, but only if it has a particular property. If it doesn't have that property, I want it to be handled just like any other exception (logging, screaming, etc.)

The code above works, but if possible, I want to avoid repeating `handle_exception_normally()` ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and all that).

Just putting `raise` in the `else` clause of the first `except` block does not work. A parent `try` block would catch that, but the catch-all clause in the same block will not.

I could nest two `try` blocks, but it's not very elegant; I'd rather just use
the code I have above.

Is there a better way?

Note that I'm using Python 3.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the keyword `raise`. Just use that by itself to handle the exception the usual way.

Comment: @RickTeachey: As I said, 'a parent try block would catch that, but the catch-all clause in the _same block_ will not.' Did you mean something else? If so, please show me the code, because it seems like you're suggesting exactly what I said I did not want.

Comment: Apologies I didn't read closely enough. I like the short-circuiting `and` approach that was suggested- pretty readable, although a bit weird since it causes you not to use the normal exception syntax. At the same time though, I don't know why you don't like the nested `try` block. It's probably the most readable way.

Comment: I suppose if the `try` blocks start on consecutive lines, it's not so bad. I generally try to avoid nesting too deeply though, because it's more difficult to see which `except` (or `else` or whatever) is associated with which condition, especially in Python where there are no curly braces.

Comment: Total agreement here. If I see more than one level of nesting- especially in `try` blocks- I tend to take it as a cue that it's time to spin out some of the logic into a separate subroutine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would opt for:

```
try:
    # do stuff
except Exception as e:
    if e.args[0] == 'Discriminate Exception Here' and sse.some_property == some_special_value:
        # handle the exception in a special way
    else:
        handle_exception_normally()
```

[Moses Koledoye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125566/moses-koledoye) proposed:

```
try:
    # do stuff
except Exception as e:
    if getattr(e, 'some_property', None) == some_special_value:
        # handle the exception in a special way
    else:
        handle_exception_normally()
```

Which is shorter but requires some_special_value to always be `!= None` and attribute to be unique to your exception.

Examples of exception discrimination, with `e.args[0]`:

```
try:
 5 / 0
except Exception as e:
 print(e.args[0])

division by zero
```

With `__class__.__name__`:

```
try:
 5 / 0
except Exception as e:
 print(e.__class__.__name__)

ZeroDivisionError
```

With `isinstance()` (bit more CPU intensive) :

```
try:
 5 / 0
except Exception as e:
 isinstance(e, ZeroDivisionError)

True
```

Comment: You can replace both conditionals with `getattr(sse, 'some_property', '') == some_special_value`, so that there'll be no need to check `e.args[0] == ...`

Answer (score 0):

I understand OP said they do not want to do this, but I'm throwing my lot in with the nested `try` block. I think it's the most readable way to go about this:

```
try:
    try:
        # do stuff
    except SomeSpecificException as sse:
        if sse.some_property == some_special_value:
            # handle the exception in a special way
        else:
            raise
except:
    handle_exception_normally()
```